# Form Validation WIth Formik and React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik

I am learning to build app using react-native and one of my screens has couple of Picker components. I want to run some basic validations on them before submitting. I want to make sure value of Picker is not null. I'm trying to use Formik for this and getting little confused. My code looks like this(stripped down):

```
<View style={{flex:1, alignItems:'center'}}>
<Formik
    initialValues={{ language: ''}}
    onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
    validationSchema={yup.object().shape({
    language: yup
        .string()
        .required()
    })}
>
    {({ values, handleChange, errors, setFieldTouched, touched, isValid, handleSubmit }) => (
    <Fragment>
        <View style={{borderRadius: 3, borderWidth: 1}}>
            <Picker style={{ height: 40, width: 400}}
                mode='dropdown'
                prompt={'Select language'}
                itemStyle={{ backgroundColor: "grey"}}
                selectedValue={this.state.selectedLanguage}
                onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => 
                    this.setState({selectedLanguage: itemValue})}>
                    <Picker.Item label='Select your language' value={null} key={0}/>
                    <Picker.Item label='Java' value={1} key={1}/>
                    <Picker.Item label='Python' value={2} key={2}/>
                    <Picker.Item label='Scala' value={3} key={3}/>
            </Picker>
        </View>

        <Button title='Submit' onPress={() => {
        this.handleSubmit()
        }}/>
    </Fragment>
    )}
</Formik>
</View>
```

Questions I have: How will Formik map to my Picker component. I am not passing any name. How do I pass the name(Language) to Picker. 
Can I validate non-null value for selectedValue before submitting?

Comment: Can you explain more about "pass the name(Language) to Picker" and "validate non-null value". What do you mean by "pass the name" and "validate"? If possible a snack playground will help.

Comment: When I am creating a validation schema, I am creating validation rules for a particular component (which is I think identified using a name). For example in this case I've created Yup validation for a component by name 'language'. How do I relate this name with my Picker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formik bag has a prop named "setFieldValue", with this you can use it in your onValueChange prop of your picker like this:

```
onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
    setFieldValue('langauge', itemValue)
    this.setState({selectedLanguage: itemValue})
}
```

Now when you submit the form it will get passed to formik with the name 'language' and the selected option.